# Oracle Create Table -> Missing Right Parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table, varbinary

I am new to writing SQL and using Oracle... so I'm sorry if this is obvious but I can't figure it out. It's telling me that I'm missing a right parenthesis but as far as I can tell they are all there. It seems to be a problem with the VARBINARY line but I don't know why.

```
CREATE TABLE DATA_VALUE
(
    DATA_ID         VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
    POSITION        INT NOT NULL,
    VALUE           VARCHAR2(50),
    BINARY_VALUE    VARBINARY(50),
    DATA_TYPE       VARCHAR2(20),

    CONSTRAINT DATA_VALUE_PK PRIMARY KEY(DATA_ID, POSITION)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

`VARBINARY` is not an Oracle data type. A quick search suggests MySQL and SQL Server have it, at least, but not Oracle. Perhaps you need to explain what you want to store in that field. The closest I can think you might mean is `RAW`.

The valid built-in datatypes are listed [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm):

> The `RAW` and `LONG RAW` data types store data that is not to be
>   explicitly converted by Oracle Database when moving data between
>   different systems. These data types are intended for binary data or
>   byte strings.

[This Microsoft article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151817.aspx) suggests you should be using `RAW` as a replacement for `VARBINARY` too, at least for the size you're talking about.

```
CREATE TABLE DATA_VALUE
(
    DATA_ID         VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
    POSITION        INT NOT NULL,
    VALUE           VARCHAR2(50),
    BINARY_VALUE    RAW(50),
    DATA_TYPE       VARCHAR2(20),

    CONSTRAINT DATA_VALUE_PK PRIMARY KEY(DATA_ID, POSITION)
);

table DATA_VALUE created.
```