# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PhotoLibrary (
    PhotoLibraryID INT IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ImageName      VARCHAR(100),
    Photo          VARBINARY(MAX)
)
```

While using the above code in SQL I am getting the error help me

Comment: `VARBINARY` is not an Oracle Data Type - [Oracle Create Table -> Missing Right Parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054379/oracle-create-table-missing-right-parenthesis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in SQL Server code to Oracle.  Big problem.

```
CREATE TABLE PhotoLibrary (
  PhotoLibraryID INT    PRIMARY KEY,
  ImageName        VARCHAR2(100),
  Photo            VARBINARY(MAX)
);
```

Oracle doesn't understand `identity`.  If you want an auto-incrementing column, then you need to use a sequence.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733085/auto-increment-for-oracle) is an example.

Comment: `VARBINARY` is not an Oracle Data Type - [Oracle Create Table -> Missing Right Parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054379/oracle-create-table-missing-right-parenthesis)